# How to Fill the Buffer in File Download Using the Network [android]

Tags: java, android, networking, download, buffer

I am working on encrypting the byte array when I download the file. However, because the network is used, data is dynamically populated even if the size of the buffer array is fixed at 4096. When re-decrypting the file, we do not use the network, so 4096 bytes are constantly coming in. Encryption and decryption problems occur in this area.

What I want to know is how the size of the bytes coming into the buffer at the time of downloading can always be filled with 4096.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is how the size of the bytes coming into the buffer at the time of downloading can always be filled with 4096.

It can't. The TCP API is free to deliver you anything from 1 byte upwards to the size of your buffer.

You need to fix the bugs in your encryption and decryption code. XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Show the code where you are downloading the file.

One way to implement it is, to loop when reading data from network and keep pushing those received bytes to a buffer till its full (e.g. 4096 for your case), and then process & empty the buffer.

You might also have to handle cases when you receive more data that you can push onto the buffer...

my two cents...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I have.
You can get buffer sizes as you want. Apply it when you need.

```
private boolean readFully(InputStream is, byte[] data, int off, int length) {
    int read;
    while (length > 0) {
        read = is.read(data, off, length);
        if(read <=0){
            return false;
        }

        length -= read;
        off += read;
    }
    return true;
}
```